# Jquery on submit not working with a generated text input

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a list of files on a server displayed on a page. I also have a button to create a folder. Clicking the button generates a new text input where a name for the folder can be entered, which is nested in an html form.
I then want to write some ajax there however the .submit function of Jquery doesn't see the newly generated text input field, therefore I cannot get this to work.
Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var csrf = "{% csrf_token %}";
var fields = 0;
$('#newFolder').click(function(){
  var folderName = $('<form method="post" class="createFolder">' + csrf + '<li><input type="checkbox" class="styled-checkbox"><div id="name"><input type="text" id="fieldName" /></div></li></form>');
  $('.objectsList').append(folderName);
  });
$('.createFolder').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("fieldName");
  });
});
```

So when you click on `#newFolder` a new li with a form is generated. I enter the name for the folder and as I click enter I get redirected to the same page but blank.
If I hardcode this form with text input it works fine.
I understand that Jquery loads along with the page and if something is generated after the page has loaded then it will not see it, correct?
How can I make it 'see' this newly generated form and its fields?

Thanks

Comment: Your case isn't json, but the dynamic content issue is the same.

Comment: you should add wrapper element and have the form(s) appended to it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @flynorc or they could just use a delegate event binding...

Comment: @Taplar is delegate event binding not the same principle that the answer of the question that I linked uses? Where you define an event listener on the parent element (that already exists) and then use the on("click", "selector", function) ?
like here:
https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: It is, now that I read your link, however your lead in text didn't express that.  It simply said add a wrapper element.  It didn't say why.  Edit: also your link would be another possibility for a close vote due to question duplication.

Comment: Is my understanding correct? I need to hardcode a form and dynamically create an element which I need to call via the submit function in Jquery?

Comment: Alright, I already got it working. Thanks guys!